# forwarding request to a page with p:outputpanel make it load forever

Tags: jsf, primefaces, servlet-3.0, wildfly-10

i m developing a web-app using primefaces 6.0 on wildfly 10, my problem is:

redirecting to a page that contain a primefaces outputpanel cause the outputpanel to load forever :/
by redirecting i mean code like:

```
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/aboutUs.xhtml");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

i will appreciate any help :D

---

after some testing, i got it:
-lets say i've sent a requset to my servlet, the requset got forwared and a nice web page it returned

-now the javascript code in my outputpanel widget try to load its contents, so it send another request

-this time the servlet my just decide to not forward to the same page, or it my not forward at all or ...

the problem is i did not write this servlet (its faces servlet in my case, and since even faces-config.xml won't do the trick it's hopless)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i've done is using a parameter to enable/disable outputpanel lazy loading like this:

```
        <p:outputPanel deferred="#{request.getParameter('lazy') == 'off'? false : true}">
```

then i used this in my auto forward pages:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml?lazy=off</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.xhtml?lazy=off</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

the rest is ensuring than any ajax call these pages do should also include this parameter so i've added this parameter in my "change language" menuitem

```
<p:menuitem ...>
     <f:param name="lazy" value="#{request.getParameter('lazy')}" />
</p:menuitem>
```

now these pages load without lazy loading insdead of loading forever, not a perfect solution but better than nothing :D

this is the best idea that i got until now :/